# Standard style to apply to broken links on a webpage

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, styles, usability

I've searched for a **standard way of styling broken links** on a webpage and only found general references to using the HTML DEL tag and striking through the linked text with CSS (like the Broken Link Checker plugin does in WordPress). From a usability perspective, I think the CSS way could be best.

Is there a standard or at least better way I haven't found?

PS: I'm not looking for a way to find and process broken links.